# C++ OpenSSL Encrypting Differently From PHP OpenSSL

Tags: php, c++, encryption

What I'm trying to do is encrypt something on my PC with OpenSSL in AES 256 CBC, and do the same thing on the server. I have figured out my encryption key, and have that working successfully. The only thing that is the issue is when I try to encrypt something. In my PHP script, I have:

```
<?php
$method = "AES-256-CBC";

$time = microtime(false);
$time = substr($time, 11, strlen($time) - 11);
$time = floor($time / 10);
$enckey = substr(md5($time), 0, 16);
$iv = $enckey;
$enckey = $enckey.$enckey;
echo $iv;
echo "\r\n";
die(base64_decode(openssl_encrypt("test", $method, $enckey, 0, $iv)));
?>
```

In C++, I have:

```
    static unsigned WriteCallback( void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp )
{
    static_cast< std::string* >( userp )->append( static_cast< char* >( contents ), size * nmemb );
    return size * nmemb;
}

std::string Encrypt( const unsigned char *szPlainText, const unsigned char *szKey, unsigned char *szIV, const int iTextLength )
{
    unsigned char szOutput[ 16 ];
    memset( szOutput, 0, sizeof( szOutput ) );

    std::string strOutput { };
    AES_KEY enc_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key( szKey, 256, &enc_key );
    AES_cbc_encrypt( szPlainText, szOutput, iTextLength, &enc_key, ( unsigned char* )szKey, AES_ENCRYPT );
    strOutput.append( reinterpret_cast< const char* >( szOutput ) );
    return strOutput;
}

std::string MD5Hash( const unsigned char *szPlainText, const int iCharacters )
{
    unsigned char chDigest[ MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH ] { };

    MD5( szPlainText, iCharacters, reinterpret_cast< unsigned char* >( &chDigest ) );

    char mdString[ 33 ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++ )
        sprintf( &mdString[ i * 2 ], "%02x", ( unsigned int )chDigest[ i ] );

    return mdString;
}

int main( )
{
    const unsigned char *szPlainText = reinterpret_cast< const unsigned char* >( "test" );
    std::string strCipher { };
    std::string strResponseBuffer { };
    std::string strEncryptionKey { };
    std::string strEncryptionKeyBuffer { };
    strEncryptionKey = MD5Hash( reinterpret_cast< const unsigned char* >( std::to_string( int( std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::seconds >( std::chrono::system_clock::now( ).time_since_epoch( ) ).count( ) / 10 ) ).c_str( ) ), std::to_string( int( std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::seconds >( std::chrono::system_clock::now( ).time_since_epoch( ) ).count( ) / 10 ) ).length( ) );
    strEncryptionKey = strEncryptionKey.substr( 0, 16 );
    strEncryptionKeyBuffer = strEncryptionKey;
    std::cout << "Our enc key before encryption: " << strEncryptionKey << std::endl;
    strCipher = Encrypt( szPlainText, reinterpret_cast< const unsigned char* >( (strEncryptionKeyBuffer + strEncryptionKeyBuffer).c_str(  ) ), ( unsigned char* )( strEncryptionKeyBuffer.c_str( ) ), strlen( reinterpret_cast< const char* >( szPlainText ) ) );

    curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
    void *vCurl = curl_easy_init( );
    curl_easy_setopt( vCurl, CURLOPT_URL, strURL );
    //curl_easy_setopt( vCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, strPostData.c_str( ) );
    curl_easy_setopt( vCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback );
    curl_easy_setopt( vCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &strResponseBuffer );
    curl_easy_perform( vCurl );
    curl_easy_cleanup( vCurl );

    std::cout << "Our time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::seconds >( std::chrono::system_clock::now( ).time_since_epoch( ) ).count( ) / 10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Our enc key: " << strEncryptionKey << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Our cipher: " << strCipher << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Our plain text: " << szPlainText << std::endl;
    std::cout << strResponseBuffer << std::endl;

    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

For output, I get:

```
Our enc key before encryption: 1bf5ecb10599c5d0
Our time: 151699880
Our enc key: 1bf5ecb10599c5d0
Our cipher: Ä▌m4#£┌7Cb,0I¡,î╠╠╠╠\æ4∞■Ü
Our plain text: test
1bf5ecb10599c5d0
╚┴Ü*@¢¢}03e░▒[
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I do not know why my ciphers are different. The encryption key is the same and I am using the same method.

Comment: I like how you `die` with the result from PHP :) Also, could it be this part in PHP: `$enckey = $enckey.$enckey;` that is doubling up your encryption key? I dont see that in the C++ side.

Comment: @IncredibleHat When I call the function I double my encryption keys. I do this just to have a different ivec from my key.

Comment: I see. Yeah, I glossed over the iv (sorry). Thats not very secure to use part of the enckey as the iv... the iv should really be a wholly randomized piece of binary. However I see the issue you have trying to reconcile encryptions between languages.  So even if you encrypt the same data on both platforms... the 'result' will look visually different (because enckey is based on time, and iv is based on enckey). However I am no encryption expert... and would rather step back and let one take over from here, for your own good ;) I don't want to screw you up!

Comment: @IncredibleHat The encryption keys are the same, and I do realize that I am using them as the ivec. I'm just testing to see if I can get it to work. The 4 characters that look like lines with something coming out to the right are there every time that I generate a cipher.

Comment: Your enckeys are the same on both sides, even though you begin with a value from time? I guess I'm confused there. It seems to me, that the keys could be slightly different every time you ran either end (as they build themselves from 'now'), which then would result in a new cipher each time. Hm. I may have to go fiddle with this for a bit ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat There is almost no delay, and I divide it by 10 so that it changes every 10 seconds rather than every second. I don't think I've had a case where the keys don't match.

Comment: Ah HA! Ok... thank you for clarifying that. Hmm. Welp... I guess you need a c++ cryptology guy to pop in here. Maybe also post this in the [stack.crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) site too for more exposure? Or have a mod migrate it.

Comment: First guesses: Trailing \0, \r, or \n on one or the other side (or both, but different).